# Is there a way to display a seaborn plot without using the python console?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am quite new to `Seaborn`, and I am in the process of learning it. However, when I try to run my code, the plot never shows up and instead, the program ends.

This is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0wRw.png):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings as wrn
from np.Importing_data import stats

plt.rcParams(['figure.figsize']l = 8, 4

wrn.filterwarnings('ignore')
sns.distplot(stats['InternetUsers'], bins=30)

# sns.boxplot(data=stats, x='IncomeGroup', y='BirthRate')
plt.show(sns)
```

The 4th line of code is importing the data. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXh1P.png) is what I get when running the code normally. The error appears in the Python console, but I do not think this is causing the plot not to be shown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Ratnes.Ratnes-LT/PycharmProjects/demo-rs/np/Seaborn.py", line 11, in <module>
        plt.show(sns)
    File "C:\Users\Ratnes.Ratnes-LT\PycharmProjects\demo-rs\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 354, in show
    return _backend_mod.show(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I try and run this on the **python console**, the code works as expected.

This is the result.

[image]

The matplotlib plots do show up but the seaborn ones don't. If anyone's got any solutions, please post on here.

Comment: Why are you trying to call matplotlib's `plt` function with `sns` from seaborn as an argument?

Comment: Hold on, I'm installing the dependencies to try this out

Comment: `plt.show()` only.

Comment: what @BigBen said, can confirm it works

Comment: This is basically what your error says:) - "you have passed more arguments than expected"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please read the document of [matplotlib.pyplot.show](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html). The only argument that can be passed as an argument is a bool value which indicates whether you need interactive or non interactive mode (default value is None), which is basically what your error says as well.

Comment: Read it just now, thanks